# Array Search Method Php

Tags: php, arrays

```
$contacts = array(
    array("name"=>"Samatha Perera", "Email"=>"smatha@gmail.com", "Telephone"=>array("office"=>"0112233789","personal"=>"0718256385","home"=>"0112843425")), 
    array( "name"=>"Charith Fernando", "Email"=>"charith@gmail.com", "Telephone"=>array("office"=> "0112656457","personal"=>"0718456723","home"=>"0112334466"))
);
```

From this array I need to search by name, email, phone number via HTML form. I have done the form and search coding part but it doesn't work.

Search code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        function search_name($id, $array){
            foreach($array as $key => $val){
                while($val['name'] === $name){
                    echo "<td>".$array['id']."</td>";
                }
            }
            return "wrong";
        }   
        $name = $_POST['val-box'];
        $id= search_name($name,$contacts);
    }
```

Comment: You've set $name after use, try putting it before your function?

Comment: You don't define `$contacts` anywhere. Or it's defined outside the code you're showing

Comment: If you could use SQL, that would expedite your quest. Otherwise, let me see if I can get something working.

Comment: i wanted to know how to used by the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$contact = array(
            array("name"=>"Samantha Perera",
                  "email"=>"samantha@gmail.com",
                  "telephone"=>
                                array("office"=>"0112233789",
                                      "personal"=>"0718256385",
                                       "home"=>"0112843425")),
            array("name"=>"Charith Fernando",
                  "email"=>"charith@gmail.com",
                  "telephone"=>
                                array("office"=>"0112656457",
                                      "personal"=>"0718456723",
                                       "home"=>"0112334466")),
            array("name"=>"Malith Wijekoon",
                  "email"=>"malith@hotmail.com",
                  "telephone"=>
                                array("office"=>"0332301311",
                                      "personal"=>"077456453",
                                      "home"=>"0112556677")),
            array("name"=>"Sanath Perera",
                  "email"=>"sanath@yahoo.com",
                  "telephone"=>
                                array("office"=>"0112201654",
                                      "personal"=>"0757277365",
                                      "home"=>"0312867725")),
            array("name"=>"Gihnan Indran",
                  "email"=>"gihan@gmail.com",
                  "telephone"=>
                                array("office"=>"032222526",
                                      "personal"=>"0778856385",
                                      "home"=>"0322243426")),
            );



     function searchValue($type, $value, $array) {
           foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
    //echo $val[$type]. "=== ".$value."<br/>";
    if($type != 'tp'){
       if ($val[$type] === $value) {
           return $key;
       }
    }else{

if ($val['telephone']['office'] === $value || $val['telephone']['personal'] === $value || $val['telephone']['home'] === $value) {
           return $key;
       }
    }
      }
          return null;
     }


       if(isset($_POST['btn_search'])){
$text = isset($_POST['search_val'])?$_POST['search_val']:null;
$type = isset($_POST['search'])?$_POST['search']:null;
$result =  searchValue($type,$text, $contact);

$data ='';
$data .= "<table class=\"resl\" width=\"800px\"><tr><td>Name</td><td>Email</td>                                 <td>Telephone</td></tr>";
$data  .= "<tr><td valign=\"top\">".$contact[$result]['name']."</td><td valign=\"top\">".$contact[$result]['email']."</td><td>Office :".$contact[$result]['telephone']['office']."</br>Personal :".$contact[$result]['telephone']['personal']."</br>Home :".$contact[$result]['telephone']['home']."</td></tr>";
$data  .= "</table>";

   }
```

this is the html part.

```
<body>
<form name="form1" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="POST">
        Search Contacts
       <table>
   <tr>
<td>Search By</td>
<td colspan="2"><select name="search">
             <option value="name" <?php echo(isset($_POST['search'])&&($_POST['search']=="name")?"selected":null); ?>>Name</option>
            <option value="email" <?php echo(isset($_POST['search'])&&($_POST['search']=="email")?"selected":null); ?>>Email</option>
            <option value="tp" <?php echo(isset($_POST['search'])&&($_POST['search']=="tp")?"selected":null); ?>>Telephone</option>
    </select>
</td>
 </tr>
            <tr>
    <td>Search Value</td>
  <td><input type="text" name="search_val" id="search_val" value="<?php echo        (isset($_POST['search_val'])?$_POST['search_val']:null) ?>"></td>
     <td><button type="submit" name="btn_search">Search</button>
        </tr>   
         </table>   
       <?php
          if(isset($data )){echo $data ;}
        ?>

    </form>
   </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

$name is sent to the function as the $id argument so
i think you mean this:

```
while($val['name'] === $name){
```

to

```
while($val['name'] === $id){
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? (you had some minor typos and mistakes.) (I removed the post from the code to test it locally, but you can easily add that code again).

```
$contacts = array(
    array("name"=>"Samatha Perera", "Email"=>"smatha@gmail.com", "Telephone"=>array("office"=>"0112233789","personal"=>"0718256385","home"=>"0112843425")), 
    array( "name"=>"Charith Fernando", "Email"=>"charith@gmail.com", "Telephone"=>array("office"=> "0112656457","personal"=>"0718456723","home"=>"0112334466"))
);
function search_name($id, $array){
    foreach($array as $key => $val){
        if($val['name'] == $id){
            echo "<td>".$val['name']."</td>" .
                 "<td>".$val['Email']."</td>" .
                 "<td>".$val['Telephone']['office'] . "</td>" .
                 "<td>".$val['Telephone']['personal'] . "</td>" .
                 "<td>".$val['Telephone']['home'] . "</td>";
        }
    }
    echo "wrong";
}


$name = 'Samatha Perera';
$id= search_name($name,$contacts);
```

Comment: @Diogo Silva is correct too, but a while will keep printing the found name (at least, when I tested it). It makes more sense too to use an if (if I understood you correctly)

Comment: thankx.. this only  will return the name. I want to know how to return the name email phone numbers also by the name.

Comment: @AZacky I added the code that returns everything, which isn't very complicated :)